# Make Exchange only hold the last 30 days email

Tags: windows-server-2003, exchange-2003

It is my understanding that Recipient Policies are the mechanism where the exchange database can be cleaned up.

I have a realtime(ish) email archiving system, which seamlessly plugs into Outlook. It has a 5 minute window, so really any email that is available in exchange, will also be available in this system, within 5 minutes.

To this end, I only wish to keep deleted emails for 7 days, and regular emails for 30 days. After configuring this, I have noticed, that my emails in my outlook are still there, which means they are in exchange, and therefore, the policy is not working - Can I get a walk through to make sure I have actually taken the steps that I think I should be?

Thank You

Comment: Which Mailbox Manager policy settings did you set? Is the mailbox management process scheduled? Has it run since you configured the policy?

Comment: I will have to check the logs I'm guessing to see if it has made a pass already. I will check this, and get back to you, although I am 100% sure that I have not seen anything in the logs to suggest that the mailbox management process is running. Is it possible to do a 'dry' run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mailbox policy like this does not take effect immediately but rather the next time the management agent makes a pass over the mailbox. If everything's correctly configured, you should find the mails you expect to be gone will be gone overnight.

Comment: I set the policy 2 weeks ago! Can I force it to run outside of it's schedule?